# VS Code not running windows 7 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I have only one Windows 7 64 bit old PC. And I learning web development and I want to run VS Code code editor but when I install VS Code and double click launching icon then VSCode does not launching.

**Confirmation my PC:**

RAM : 4GB (DDR4)

HDD : 500 GB

CPU : Dual Core Processors

GPU:

OS : Windows 7 64bit

I am the first on this platform so please forgive me if I have made any mistakes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also still use Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.  I discovered that the latest version of Code downloaded directly from Microsoft - 1.74.3 at the time I'm writing this - runs fine and all features (like debugging) appear to work *IF* you use the ZIP download. Every time I start it, it pops up the message "Visual Studio Code on Windows 7 will no longer receive any further updates."  But when the next update comes along, I plan to just download the newest zip.

Note that all the projects I had opened in the installed version are still available in the zipped version.  So, I won't be upgrading this system to Windows 10.

Comment: still working just fine as of 1.81.0 (August 2023)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can install [Visual Studio Code v1.70.3](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70).

P.s. It works well in my computer.

Comment: ... or you can download a ZIP with an up-to-date version instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to God a genius guy made the newer VSCode compatible with windows 7, i was able to run the latest version v1.87 with absolutely no problem. https://github.com/Alex313031/codium
https://thorium.rocks/codium/

[image]

a rich discussion is going here https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1264

Alex313031 made also the newer chromium compatible with windows 7

Answer (score -1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70
this is last supported version for Windows7

Comment: it's the last _officially_ supported version. Later versions work on Windows 7 without any problems, you just need to install them manually

Answer (score -2):

> Hardware# Visual Studio Code is a small download (< 200 MB) and has a
> disk footprint of < 500 MB. VS Code is lightweight and should easily
> run on today's hardware.
>
> We recommend:
>
> 1.6 GHz or faster processor 1 GB of RAM Platforms# VS Code is supported on the following platforms:
>
> OS X El Capitan (10.11+) **Windows 8.0, 8.1 and 10**, 11 (32-bit and
> 64-bit) Linux (Debian): Ubuntu Desktop 16.04, Debian 9 Linux (Red
> Hat): Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, CentOS 7, Fedora 34

Comment: Thank you sir. Is not there any way to run vs code on Windows 7?

Comment: You are welcome You need to have at least Windows 8 or above https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

Comment: Yes, there is a way to run VS Code on Windows 7.  See my answer above - use a zip download.